# How do you check a checkbox without firing a change event?

Tags: javascript, extjs, dom-events

I have simple checkbox:

```js
r = new Ext.form.Checkbox({
    listeners: {
        check: function(checkbox, checked) {
        }
    }
}

r.setValue(true);
```

How to check checkbox without fireevent check ( I want to fireevent check ONLY from mouse click ) ? (setValue doesn't work ).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should suspend events before set the value and resume events after this. For example:

```
myCheckBox.suspendEvents(false); // Stop all events. 
                                 //Be careful with it. Dont forget resume events!
myCheckBox.setValue(!myCheckBox.getValue()); // invert value
myCheckBox.resumeEvents(); // resume events
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just set

```
r.checked = true,
```

does that not work? although it should work.

Answer (score 1):

> Why dont you just set r.checked = true, does that not work?

Setting checked attributes will have affect only for non-rendered control to assign initial control value. After rendering you can't use this to change value.

Suspend/Resume events is good practice to change control value without sending notifications.

Also you can put checked state immedially to dom element:

`item.el.dom.checked = true;`

Answer (score 0):

I was already trying the accepted answer before googling but it didn't work in 4.1.3.  The following did:

```
myCheckBox.setRawValue(true);
```

Hope this helps future googlers.

Comment: Just a note of caution: by using "setRawValue", the first uncheck event will not fire. Source: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?263404-Checkbox-does-not-fire-quot-change-quot-event-on-the-first-change-after-setRawValue(true).&s=2fb682a6d30f35675c73e5c6230c476d

Answer (score 0):

Calling `suspendEvents(false)` before setting the value and `resumeEvents()` afterwards is a more generic approach than `setRawValue` because if you're using converters (say, `1` is `true` and `0` is `false`) they will remain working.