# Only Listen for change to checkbox when it is checked by the user and not by my code?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of posts and each post has a checkbox at the top and at the bottom. And I am trying to ensure that the checkboxes stay in sync with eachother:

This code works in one direction: so if you click the top checkbox, it will tick the bottom checkbox for you:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.mypost').forEach((i) => {
    var my_buttonTop = i.querySelector('.button-check-top .button-check');
    var my_buttonBottom = i.querySelector('.button-check-bottom .button-check');

    my_buttonTop.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        my_buttonBottom.click();
    })
});
```

However, I want it to work both ways so I added an EvenListener for the other checkbox as well:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.mypost').forEach((i) => {
    var my_buttonTop = i.querySelector('.button-check-top .button-check');
    var my_buttonBottom = i.querySelector('.button-check-bottom .button-check');

    my_buttonTop.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        my_buttonBottom.click();
    })
    my_buttonBottom.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        my_buttonTop.click();
    })
    
});
```

Now the two conflicts with eachother, because the code "clicks" the checkbox and then it triggers the EventListener all over again.
So I need some way to trigger the eventlistener only when the user clicks the checkbox and not when the status of the checkbox is changed by my code.

I have searched all over for potential solutions online, but I only find potential jquery solutions and I want to do this in javascript.

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961625/how-do-you-check-a-checkbox-without-firing-a-change-event

Comment: Can you add enough code to reproduce this behaviour? Because, ordinarily, JavaScript initiated events don't trigger event-listeners (as a simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fgj8mhxr/ )

Comment: Check the value of `event.isTrusted`.  It should be `true` on user generated clicks and `false` on code generated clicks.  Note, that as written, your code could allow the checkboxes to get out of sync such that checking one would uncheck the other.  You likely do want to use what @DavidThomas used in their example, and do something like `my_otherButton.checked = event.target.checked`.